# How can I make IntelliJ recognise @Theory tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit4

I'm working on a large existing project using a new installation of IntelliJ on a new workstation. Many unit test classes in the project use the JUnit 4 @Theory annotation to run parameterised tests.  If I run a whole test class in IntelliJ, the @Theory tests are included and run successfully. The tests also run correctly in Maven.

But the IntelliJ IDE does not seem to recognise the @Theory tests as runnable methods, as there is no green 'run' icon in the margin, and the right-click menu by the method name does not include the run options.

How can I get the IDE to recognise these tests?

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.5 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.5281.24, built on June 12, 2018
macOS 10.12.6

Comment: Could be this issue: [IDEA-189553](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189553)/[IDEA-189526](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-189526). You can check the 2018.2 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion where mentioned issue was fixed.

Comment: Thanks Andrey. IDEA-189553 is exactly the problem. The ticket says it's fixed, but it presumably didn't get into the June 12 build. I guess it's just a matter of waiting.

Comment: The `182.3341.11` Build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion contains the fix.